# I need help with dog training treat for my Siberian Husky

Tags: dogs, training, diet

I have a siberian husky puppy which is gonna be 3 months old this July 11. I tried training him using his dog food and some JerHigh Beef/Bacon dog treats but he doesn't pay much attention to them even we are in a closed room. I'm thinking it was the treat that's not interesting.

How will I know what kind/flavor of treat my dog likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will know because he will go bonkers for it, though some dogs are not highly food motivated.
Some people will cook chicken and chop it up in little pieces, you may try that.

Doing training when they are hungry is the ideal time to do it. He will be more motivated to listen to you when he knows you have the goods :).

Are you doing clicker training?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I haven't used a clicker for the last month I am training him. I just got the clicker yesterday and I like it to be exciting.. If he's not food motivated, what are the other things that may motivate him & how to apply it while training?

Comment: I'm sure if he's hungry he'll be motivated, good times would be before breakfast and before supper.

If he's not then good praise works too, talk to him in a happy/pleased voice (like "Good boy!") give him lots of kisses and pets. At the end of the training session give him his full breakfast/supper or do his favorite activity (like playing fetch), end on a high note.

Answer (score 1):

I've used rare beef liver with great success before. Just throw it on the pan for a couple of minutes to brown it. No salt, no oil, just braised meat. They LOVE it. Liver tends to be pretty inexpensive, and you can store it in the fridge for up to a week after it's cooked.

I'm sure he'll go crazy for it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some dogs respond to toys more than food. Or fetching a ball, or playing tug, etc. Experiment with different things and see what works best. As others have said, higher value foods like chicken or liver may work well too. Just be sure to cut them into vary small pieces if you are doing a lot of training.

Answer (score 0):

We used to cut liver into small pieces, quick fry it, and then let it cool and freeze it.  Then we'd use it for snacks for him.